# Problem with energy conservation in field theory

Tags: energy-conservation, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

As it's known, for conservation of energy by Noether Theorem it's neccesery that equation below is satisfied

$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$

Where $T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\partial^\nu\psi-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$ is energy-momentum tensor

In case of Dirac equation

$T^{\mu\nu}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi-\eta^{\mu\nu}(i\bar{\psi}\not{\partial}\psi-m\bar{\psi}\psi)$

If I did everything right

$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=m\partial^\nu(\bar{\psi}\psi)$

Similar result you can get for Klein-Gordon-Fock equation

$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=m^2\partial^\nu(\bar{\psi}\psi)$

Which is obviously not zero. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're confusing kinematics with dynamics. If Noether's procedure were about generating divergence free combinations of arbitrary functions, people would be less interested in it.

Answer (score 4):

You made a mistake in calculating your divergences. As @Connor Behan commented, conservation is only valid on shell, i.e. you'll need to use the equations of motion.

In the case of Klein-Gordon:
\begin{align}
\mathcal L &= \frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi^2-m^2\phi^2) \\
\partial^2\phi+m^2\phi &= 0 \\
T^{\mu\nu} &= \partial^\mu\phi\partial^\nu\phi -\eta^{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi^2-m^2\phi^2) \\
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} &= \partial^\nu\phi\partial^2\phi+(\partial_\mu\partial^\nu\phi)\partial^\mu\phi -(\partial_\mu \phi(\partial^\mu\partial^\nu \phi)-m^2\phi\partial^\nu\phi) \\
&= \partial^\nu\phi(\partial^2\phi+m^2\phi) \\
&= 0 &&\text{(used EoM’s)}
\end{align}

In the case of Dirac:
\begin{align}
\mathcal L &= \bar \psi(i\not \partial -m)\psi \\
(i\not \partial -m)\psi  &= 0 \\
\bar \psi (i\overleftarrow {\not \partial} +m) &= 0 \\
T^{\mu\nu} &= i\bar \psi \gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi -\eta^{\mu\nu}\bar \psi(i\not \partial -m)\psi \\
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} &= i(\partial_\mu\bar \psi) \gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi + i\bar \psi \not \partial \partial^\nu\psi-(\partial^\nu \bar \psi)(i\not \partial -m)\psi-\bar \psi(i\not \partial -m)\partial^\nu\psi \\
&= \bar \psi (i\overleftarrow{\not \partial} +m)\partial^\nu\psi - \bar \psi (i \not \partial -m)\psi \\
&= 0 &&\text{(used EoM’s)}
\end{align}

Hope this helps.